# Alternative to Java Reflections

Tags: java, excel, frameworks, automation, keyword

Are there any solution to get rid of using Java reflections in my case. Please see the following for my requirement.

1. A java project is created containing different 5 classes and 5 methods in each class.
2. These methods are listed in an excel. Example: In a single column in excel I specify the following: Method2 from Class1, Method 5 from Class4 and Method 3 from Class 2
3. When I execute my program(another Junit method), It should call the methods in the above order and upon successful execution should display result.

Comment: You could generate code from your excel sheet, compile it and then run it. This can all be done from within the same JVM.

Comment: Why not use reflection though? It is designed for just these kind of requirements.